# is there any NodeJS equivalent to Drools + CSV Decision Tables?

Tags: node.js, csv, drools, rule-engine, business-rules

I followed the tutorial in [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jboss-drools/drools-decision-table-example/)

and have a running example of java with the input is decision table defined in csv files. Of course, in the way of knowledgeBuilder, not line-by-line such as in exceljs module

Now that I want to have the same program in JavaScript NodeJS. However, I don't know what is the equivalent for reading the defined CSV files

Is there a way to do that in NodeJS?
In Java, we have knowledgeBuilder class, what is equivalent of that in NodeJS??

Comment: Wait a second... Are you trying to find a way to parse a decision table defined in CSV format in NodeJs? Or you also want to "execute" that CSV? There is an entire framework behind that simple `KnowledgeBuilder` class that is used to execute the rules generated from a CSV file. Shouldn't your question be: is there any NodeJS equivalent to Drools + Decision Tables?

Comment: @Esteban: edited title

Comment: you can continue to develop the client side of the "program" in JS, while interact with the Drools decision table via REST api, for instance using the project on kie-server. Drools is a JVM project.